# How to resolve access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a API endpoint i.e. http://api.example.com/contact and it is working when I tried to use the POST method but when I configured the SSL certificate with this then the URL is changed https://api.example.com/contact but method POST is not working. I have tried with the bellow code

```
    let response = await fetch(ApiUrlConstant.getApiFullUrl("web.contact"), {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "https://api.example.com/",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
        "method": "POST",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
```

Whenever I tried method POST then I got this error

> www.example.com/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com/contact' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I have gone through the article and discussion on StackOverflow but in my case, It's not working. Now it's hard to understand which one is correct or where I did wrong?

Comment: looks like a misconfigured server

Comment: @Bravo Sorry, I din't get you?

Comment: the server is misconfigured - it's redirecting a pre-flight request when it shouldn't

Comment: @Bravo How can we solve it?

Comment: fix the server - is it yours?

Comment: @Bravo,   yes, It's mine. I think you are talking about this `        location / {
                proxy_pass http://ip_address:5000/; # whatever port your app runs on
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }`  Am I right?

Comment: no idea, it's your setup